# Unable to Install and move APK files on SD-card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, apk

I have an E-tel(curiosity i110) mobile device running on android 4.42. 
I tried to install Apps using APK files to my SD card but i couldn't. 
My problem is that I cannot move Apps which already installed to SD-card. 
When I check app manger, I seems **move to SD card** button is **fade out**. 
My question is, why my android OS blocked this feature? 
What can i do? 
How to select default APK installer as SD card without rooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if **move to SD card** option is fade out, then you can't move apps to SD card. The apps installed by user could be moved to SD-card to save internal storage.

There are some system apps which could not be moved to SD-card because OS doesn't allows that.

This may be also app specific, as *whatsapp* or *any game*, because block to move their data. Some apps you can move or some you can't.

If it is not possible without rooting, you can go to root your phone and install **Link2SD** , by which you can create a partition on your SD card and install apps on that.

Comment: Thank you so much VPN. But i can't move Chrome , Hangouts  etc..

Comment: Those are system apps, you can't move them normally. Better is to root your phone and use link2SD, by which you can also remove unwanted system apps.

Comment: Is android OS depend on mobile modal? I mean I assume that there are  tow models of phone which Samsung and HTC that inbuilt same OS assume android 4.42. These OS does contain some differences?

Comment: Yes, Every mobile company place different UI on their mobile phones, also some different features for same android version.

Comment: I understand VPN. But i bought this mobile in last weekend so I have one year warranty with it. If i do that, is it avoid to my warranty?

Comment: Rooting will void warranty

Comment: Then do you have an another way to do this?

Comment: possible there is another way, but I don't have too much research about that, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for you some your helps. If i have another, I'll tell you.